# Create variable in SAS that is calculated from other variables

Tags: statistics, sas

I have a big data set called `BRFSS` with data on `AGE`, `SEX`, whether the respondent has had a mammogram (`HADMAM`), and how long it has been since their mammogram (`HOWLONG`).  I would like to create a new calculated variable called `_MAM502Y` that is defined by this SAS code:

```
IF SEX=2 AND AGE GE 50 THEN DO;
 IF HADMAM=1 THEN DO;
       IF HOWLONG IN (1,2) THEN _MAM502Y=1;
  ELSE IF HOWLONG IN (3,4,5) THEN _MAM502Y=2;
  ELSE IF HOWLONG IN (7,9) THEN _MAM502Y=9;
  END;
 ELSE IF HADMAM=2 THEN _MAM502Y=2;
 ELSE IF HADMAM IN (7,9,.) THEN _MAM502Y=9;
 END;
ELSE IF SEX=2 AND AGE IN (.,7,9) THEN _MAM502Y=9;
ELSE  _MAM502Y=.;
```

I have a lot of experience using R for data manipulation but I need to create this variable in SAS.  Could someone tell me how I use this code in SAS to create the new variable?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a table TABLE1 in SAS library LIB1.

To make the new variable a permanent part of the original table do this (rewrite the source table):

```
data LIB1.TABLE1;
  set LIB1.TABLE1;
  ... your code..
run;
```

To create new copy of source table + new field. just change `data LIB1.TABLE1;` above to e.g. `data LIB1.TABLE2;`

To create something like original data + new calculated field (not stored), create a SAS datastep view like this (this just defines the calculation (program), no data is written, so it's done in no time (good for playing):

```
data LIB1.VIEW1 / view = LIB1.VIEW1;
  set LIB1.TABLE1;
  ... your code..
run;
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try your first option: "ERROR: You cannot open TMP1.CDBRFS04.DATA for output access with member-level control because
TMP1.CDBRFS04.DATA is in use by you in resource environment DATASTEP."

Comment: Could it be you're running some other data step against this table? TMP1 - are you opening this library by double-clicking on the SAS table in windows explorer :-)

Comment: Yes you're right, I was double-clicking the data set.  Once I opened it as a permanent data set instead, your code worked!